# Backward Heat Equation with Transversality Condition

Tags: partial-differential-equations, heat-equation

I have a backward parabolic equation of the form:

\begin{equation}
W_{\eta} + aW_{xx} - bW = 0 
\end{equation}

s.t.

\begin{equation}
\lim_{\eta \rightarrow \infty}(x,\eta) = g(x)
\end{equation}

were $x \in \mathbb{R}$, $\eta \geqslant 0$, and $a,b$ are positive constants.

Applying the following transformations:

\begin{align}
W(x,\eta) &= U(x,t)e^{b\eta} \\
t &= a\eta
\end{align}

we would get the backward heat equation below

\begin{equation}
U_{t} = - U_{xx}
\end{equation}

However, the transversality condition becomes a problem, since as $\eta \rightarrow \infty$, $e^{b\eta} \rightarrow \infty$.

Usually, if the terminal condition is of the form

\begin{equation}
W(x,H) = g(x)
\end{equation}

with $H$ finite, we could "reverse" it, that is, we could apply the following transformation:

\begin{equation}
\nu = H - \eta
\end{equation}

to obtain

\begin{equation}
-W_{\nu} + aW_{xx} - bW =  0
\end{equation}

s.t.

\begin{equation}
W(x,0) = g(x)
\end{equation}

which we can solve the traditional way (Fourier transform). However, as my terminal condition happens only at infinity I can't apply the reverse transformation above, thus I don't know how to overcome this problem. Any hint or reference?

Comment: Have you tried solving the equation with $U(x,T)=g(x)$ and let $T\to\infty$?

Comment: I have edited the question, now it reflects properly the problem I have.